# Sqlite iPhone data insertion problem

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, sqlite

Hi I have a function which basically tries to insert some data returned from a REST call.

```
- (void)syncLocalDatabase{
 NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pickuplines" ofType:@"db"];
 NSMutableString *query = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@""];
 sqlite3 *database = NULL;
 char *errorMsg = NULL;
 if (sqlite3_open([file UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
  for(PickUpLine *pickupline in pickUpLines){
   [query appendFormat:@"INSERT INTO pickuplines VALUES(%d,%d,%d,'%@','YES')", pickupline.line_id, pickupline.thumbsUps, pickupline.thumbsDowns, [pickupline.line stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"`"]];
   NSLog(query);
   int result = sqlite3_exec(database, [query UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errorMsg);
   if (result!=SQLITE_OK) {
    printf("\n%s",errorMsg);
    sqlite3_free(errorMsg);
   }
   //sqlite3_step([query UTF8String]);
   [query setString:@""];
  }//end for
 }//end if
 [query release];
 sqlite3_close(database); }
```

everything seems fine query string in log statement is also fine but the data does not gets inserted. Where as a counterpart of this function for select statement works well.
Here is the counter part

```
    - (void)loadLinesFromDatabase{

 NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pickuplines" ofType:@"db"];
 sqlite3 *database = NULL;
 if (sqlite3_open([file UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
  sqlite3_exec(database, "SELECT * FROM pickuplines", MyCallback, linesFromDatabase, NULL);
 }
 sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

I have implemented callback & it works fine.

I am a little new to Sqlite can someone please point out what am I doing wrong. 
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Crystalminds' SQLiteDatabase:
http://www.crystalminds.nl/?p=1342

They made an incredibly easy-to-use Database Library, so no more problems with difficult code! I've been using this for some time now, and i can't imagine having to do without!